# Node.js - Must use import to load ES Module:

Tags: node.js

I googled for a while but I could not find a solution that fixed my issue.

I want to use the fetch function from "node-fetch", but when requiring it in my code, I get the error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/xvma/stuff/Projekte/React/first-try/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/xvma/stuff/Projekte/React/first-try/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from /Users/xvma/stuff/Projekte/React/first-try/test.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/xvma/stuff/Projekte/React/first-try/node_modules/node-fetch/package.json.
```

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrOJo.png)

[In this file I want to use fetch()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajlsa.png)

[My server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcChD.png)

I hope you guys can help me, I tried deleting my node-components folder & package lock but that did not work.
Also, in my package.lock.json "type"="module" is not set.

Comment: Please don't post your errors and code as images!

Comment: You do not need require "node-fetch" to use fetch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `node-fetch` 3, which is only distributed as an ESM module, not `require()`able CJS modules.

- For the time being, you can just downgrade to a `node-fetch` less than version 3.
- Alternately, you can go all in on ESM and rename your script to `server.mjs` and use `import` everywhere.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot!